# What's the field for the main content for XML export?

Tags: ee2, templates, export, xml

I found this snippet of XML code (http://www.phpdevtips.com/2011/08/how-to-import-an-expressionengine-blog-into-wordpress/) that has everything set up for the XML export of one of my client's old site. The snippet is able to export all the post data, except for the main content itself. What field should I use for the `content:encoded`?

They have EE 2.5.2.

```
<xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" >

<!-- To import this information into a WordPress site follow these steps: -->
<!--RUN THIS FILE IN FIREFOX OR IE-->
<!--VIEW PAGE SOURCE-->
<!--COPY-PASTE PAGE SOURCE INTO TEXT EDITOR AND SAVE AS .WXR FILE-->
<!--REMOVE "?'s" FROM XML VERSION AT TOP OF THIS PAGE-->
<!--COMMENT OUT LINE 1309, 1310, 1311 IN wp-includes/kses.php -->
<!--THEN FOLLOW THE STEPS BELOW-->

<!-- 1. Log in to that site as an administrator. -->
<!-- 2. Go to Tools: Import in the WordPress admin panel. -->
<!-- 3. Install the "WordPress" importer from the list. -->
<!-- 4. Activate & Run Importer. -->
<!-- 5. Upload this file using the form provided on that page. -->
<!-- 6. You will first be asked to map the authors in this export file to users -->
<!--    on the site. For each author, you may choose to map to an -->
<!--    existing user on the site or to create a new user. -->
<!-- 7. WordPress will then import each of the posts, pages, comments, categories, etc. -->
<!--    contained in this file into your site. -->

<!-- generator="WordPress/3.1.2" created="2011-07-09 05:45" -->
<rss version="2.0"
    xmlns:excerpt="http://wordpress.org/export/1.1/excerpt/"
    xmlns:content="http://purl.org/rss/1.0/modules/content/"
    xmlns:wfw="http://wellformedweb.org/CommentAPI/"
    xmlns:dc="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/"
    xmlns:wp="http://wordpress.org/export/1.1/"
>

<channel>
    <title>{site_name}</title>
    <link>{site_url}</link>
    <description>{site_description}</description>
    <pubDate></pubDate>
    <language>en</language>
    <wp:wxr_version>1.1</wp:wxr_version>
    <wp:base_site_url>http://example.com:8080/</wp:base_site_url>
    <wp:base_blog_url>http://example.com:8080</wp:base_blog_url>

    <generator>http://wordpress.org/?v=3.1.2</generator>

{exp:weblog:entries weblog="default_site" orderby="date" sort="desc" limit="500" offset="0" rdf="off"}  
    <item>
        <title>{exp:xml_encode}{title}{/exp:xml_encode}</title>
        <link></link>
        <pubDate>{entry_date format="%r"}</pubDate>
        <dc:creator><![CDATA[{author}]]></dc:creator>
        <guid isPermaLink="false">http://example.com:8080/?p={entry_id}</guid>
        <description></description>
        <content:encoded><![CDATA[{if blog_content}{blog_content}{if:elseif     cc_content}{cc_content}{if:else}{entryContent}{/if}]]></content:encoded>
        <!--<content:encoded><![CDATA[{if body}{body}{if:elseif cc_content}{cc_content}{if:else}{article_content}{/if}]]></content:encoded>-->
        <excerpt:encoded><![CDATA[{if blog_short}{blog_short}{if:elseif cc_teaser}{cc_teaser}{if:else}{teaser}{/if}]]></excerpt:encoded>
        <wp:post_id></wp:post_id>
        <wp:post_date>{entry_date format="%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s"}</wp:post_date>
        <wp:post_date_gmt>{gmt_date format="%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s"}</wp:post_date_gmt>
        <wp:comment_status>open</wp:comment_status>
        <wp:ping_status>open</wp:ping_status>
        <wp:post_name>{url_title}</wp:post_name>
        <wp:status>{if status == "open"}publish{if:elseif status == "review"}pending{if:elseif status == "closed"}private{if:elseif status == "draft"}draft{if:else}publish{/if}</wp:status>
        <wp:post_parent>0</wp:post_parent>
        <wp:menu_order>0</wp:menu_order>
        <wp:post_type>post</wp:post_type>
        <wp:post_password></wp:post_password>
        <wp:is_sticky>0</wp:is_sticky>
{categories}
        <category domain="category" nicename="{if category_url_title == "uncategorized"}media{if:else}{category_url_title}{/if}"><![CDATA[{if category_name == "Uncategorized"}Media{if:else}{category_name}{/if}]]></category>
{/categories}
        <wp:postmeta>
            <wp:meta_key>_edit_last</wp:meta_key>
            <wp:meta_value><![CDATA[1]]></wp:meta_value>
        </wp:postmeta>
{if article_links}
        <wp:postmeta>
            <wp:meta_key>Associated Links</wp:meta_key>
            <wp:meta_value><![CDATA[{article_links}]]></wp:meta_value>
        </wp:postmeta>
{/if}
        <wp:postmeta>
            <wp:meta_key>_su_rich_snippet_type</wp:meta_key>
            <wp:meta_value><![CDATA[none]]></wp:meta_value>
        </wp:postmeta>
        <wp:postmeta>
            <wp:meta_key>_encloseme</wp:meta_key>
            <wp:meta_value><![CDATA[1]]></wp:meta_value>
        </wp:postmeta>
{exp:comment:entries sort="desc" entry_id="{entry_id}"}
        <wp:comment>
            <wp:comment_id>{comment_id}</wp:comment_id>
            <wp:comment_author><![CDATA[{name}]]></wp:comment_author>
            <wp:comment_author_email>{url_or_email}</wp:comment_author_email>
            <wp:comment_author_url>{url}</wp:comment_author_url>
            <wp:comment_author_IP>{ip_address}</wp:comment_author_IP>
            <wp:comment_date>{comment_date format="%Y-%m-%d %h:%i:%s"}</wp:comment_date>
            <wp:comment_date_gmt>{gmt_comment_date format="%Y-%m-%d %h:%i:%s"}</wp:comment_date_gmt>
            <wp:comment_content><![CDATA[{comment}]]></wp:comment_content>
            <wp:comment_approved>1</wp:comment_approved>
            <wp:comment_type></wp:comment_type>
            <wp:comment_parent>0</wp:comment_parent>
            <wp:comment_user_id>0</wp:comment_user_id>
        </wp:comment>
{/exp:comment:entries}
    </item>
{/exp:weblog:entries}
</channel>
</rss>
</xml>
```

Answer (score 1):

EE lets you assign arbitrary field names to your content - so there is no 'default' field name for this.  EE uses standard field names for some meta-data (e.g. `{entry_id}` is always the index number for an entry etc.), but not for content.

The use of standard field names probably explains why your script works at all, but without modifying it to reflect the field name definitions set up for your EE site, it is unlikely to provide useful output.